# Django | Al crear usuario con forms, no da error, pero no guarda el nuevo usuario en la base de datos

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Al registrar nuevo usuario mediante form, no da ningún error, pero no guarda el usuario. ¿Qué sucede?
Gracias.

**Archivo** users>models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from .managers import UserManager

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M','Masculino'),
        ('F','Femenino'),
        ('O','Otros'),
    )

    username = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email',]

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username
    
    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name + '' + self.last_name
```

**Archivo** users>managers.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager

class UserManager(BaseUserManager, models.Manager):

    def _create_user(self, username, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, is_active, **extra_fields):
        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=email,
            is_staff=is_staff,
            is_superuser=is_superuser,
            is_active=is_active,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user
    
    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, False, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, True, True, True, **extra_fields)
    
    def cod_validation(self, id_user, cod_registro):
        if self.filter(id=id_user, codregistro=cod_registro).exists():
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

**Archivo** users>forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import User

class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label = 'Contraseña',
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder':'Contraseña'
            }
        )
    )

    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label = 'Contraseña',
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                'placeholder':'Repetir contraseña'
            }
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'email',
            'name',
            'last_name',
            'gender'

        )
    def clean_password2(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
            self.add_error('password2', 'Las contraseñas no son iguales')
```

**Archivo** templates>login.html

```
<h1>Registrar nuevo usuario</h1>
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Registrar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Debería funcionar correctamente, pues todo esta bien... pero sospecho que se trata del método `clean_password2`, debe retornar el `password2` para indicar que no hay ningún error (`return self.cleaned_data['password2']`), intenta corrigiendo eso, si no funciona actualiza tu pregunta adjuntando la vista.

Comment: ¿Por otra parte porque no usas el form [`UserCreationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm)? hace exactamente lo que estas haciendo...